# what does in c++ for example means typedef void(Number:: *Action)(int &);

Tags: c++, typedef

Hi i have this command pattern example from the web , but there is something i dont understand is the typedef thing , what is the * Action represns here i dont even have this method defined ... here is the code example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Number
{
  public:
    void dubble(int &value)
    {
        value *= 2;
    }
};

class Command
{
  public:
    virtual void execute(int &) = 0;
};

class SimpleCommand: public Command
{
    typedef void(Number:: *Action)(int &);
    Number *receiver;
    Action action;
  public:
    SimpleCommand(Number *rec, Action act)
    {
        receiver = rec;
        action = act;
    }
     /*virtual*/void execute(int &num)
    {
        (receiver-> *action)(num);
    }
};

class MacroCommand: public Command
{
    vector < Command * > list;
  public:
    void add(Command *cmd)
    {
        list.push_back(cmd);
    }
     /*virtual*/void execute(int &num)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
          list[i]->execute(num);
    }
};

int main()
{
  Number object;
  Command *commands[3];
  commands[0] = &SimpleCommand(&object, &Number::dubble);

  MacroCommand two;
  two.add(commands[0]);
  two.add(commands[0]);
  commands[1] = &two;

  MacroCommand four;
  four.add(&two);
  four.add(&two);
  commands[2] = &four;

  int num, index;
  while (true)
  {
    cout << "Enter number selection (0=2x 1=4x 2=16x): ";
    cin >> num >> index;
    commands[index]->execute(num);
    cout << "   " << num << '\n';
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "typedef void (*Something)()" mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982470/what-does-typedef-void-something-mean)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `typedef` defines a pointer to a function which is a method of class `Number` and accepts an `int`.

Note that when you provide an actual function, it's `dubble`, and it is implemented. But you can add more, and when you do - you would only change the `Number` class, not the `Command` and others.

Comment: but why i need the typedef here ? can't i just declare the pointer to function ?
also i dont understand in the example what is the Action class ? i didn't define any Action class

Comment: @user63898: I downvoted your question, because you don't read all the answers before asking further question!

Comment: Many people find the pointer to member syntax somewhat difficult to read; the typedef simplifies it.

Answer (score 2):

using http://www.cdecl.org (a very useful site) with `void(Number:: *Action)(int &)` as input (note that it does not handle `typedefs`) gives this:

> declare Action as pointer to member of
>   class Number function (reference to
>   int) returning void Warning:
>   Unsupported in C -- 'pointer to member
>   of class' Warning: Unsupported in C --
>   'reference'

Answer (score 1):

```
 typedef void(Number:: *Action)(int &);
```

This typedef defines a type with name `Action`. The type `Action` is a member-function-pointer to a member function of class `Number` whose parameter type is `int&` and return type is `void`.

Since `Action` is the name of the type, that is why you see this name in constructor of `SimpleCommand`.

```
SimpleCommand(Number *rec, Action act)
{               //see this ^^^^^^ - being used as type!
    receiver = rec;
    action = act;
}
```