# What does "typedef void (*task) ()" do?

Tags: c++, typedef

This question is partially answered here [What does "typedef void (*Something)()" mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982470/what-does-typedef-void-something-mean)

But the answer is not completely clear to me.

if I write

```
typedef void (*task) ();
```

How does it expand?

```
thread_pool(unsigned int num_threads, task tbd) {
      for(int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        the_pool.push_back(thread(tbd));
      }
    }
```

Would it look like this?

```
thread_pool(unsigned int num_threads, (*task) () tbd) {
      for(int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        the_pool.push_back(thread(tbd));
      }
    }
```

Probably not, because it is a syntax error. I hope you can clear things up for me.

Code example is from http://www.thesaguaros.com/openmp-style-constructs-in-c11.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like this:

```
thread_pool(unsigned int num_threads, void (*tbd) ())
```

That is, the type is the function signature, the only "word" in which is "void."  The typedef name "task" disappears in this example because we aren't using the typedef anymore.